# Can reduce below code in single line using java 8 lambda?

Tags: java, lambda

Record fetching from db, can i reduce below line.

```
List<Object[]> rows = query.getResultList();
List<Map<Object, Object>> results= new ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>();

for (Iterator<Object[]> iterator = rows.iterator(); iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object[] objects = (Object[]) iterator.next();
    HashMap d= new HashMap();
    d.put("name", objects[0]);
    d.put("id", objects[1]);
    results.add(d);
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with that code? Why do you feel urged to put it in a 1-liner? (Just curious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the perfect use case for the [new Java 9 API](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V-):

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> results=rows.stream()
    .map(objects -> Map.<Object,Object>of("name", objects[0], "id", objects[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or, if you don’t insist on the map keys to be `Object`:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> results=rows.stream()
    .map(objects -> Map.of("name", objects[0], "id", objects[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Without this, there is no concise way of creating such a map (that’s why the new methods will be added to the API). The straight-forward way is either, to use a loop or to create a map factory method yourself, as [fabian’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35171827/2711488) shows.

His “one of the ugliest one-liners I've ever written” is indeed not very recommend, however, it can be simplified:

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> results = rows.stream()
    .map(x->Stream.of(0,1).collect(Collectors.toMap(i->i==0?(Object)"name":"id",i->x[i])))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It’s a single statement, or a “one-liner” with the appropriate formatting, but since you can place almost everything into one line, the term “one-liner” has little meaning anyway.

Despite being a single statement, it’s not less code compared to a straight forward for-each loop…

Answer (score 1):

Reduce to a single line? Wouldn't recommend it. You could rewrite it however using a helper method, which you could use to make this a one-liner:

```
public static Map<Object, Object> arrayToMap(Object[] objects) {
    HashMap<Object, Object> d = new HashMap<>();
    d.put("name", objects[0]);
    d.put("id", objects[1]);
    return d;
}
```

```
    List<Map<Object, Object>> results
            = rows.stream().map(ClassName::arrayToMap).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>::new));
```

An alternative not using lambdas to simplify your code (but definetly more than a single line) would be using a enhanced for loop:

```
for (Object[] objects : rows) {
    HashMap<Object, Object> d= new HashMap<>();
    d.put("name", objects[0]);
    d.put("id", objects[1]);
    results.add(d);
}
```

---

PS: It really hurts my feelings to post this code, but here's one of the ugliest one-liners I've ever written (it also has suboptimal performance):

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> results
                = rows.stream().map(x -> Arrays.stream(new Integer[] {0, 1}).collect(Collectors.<Integer, Object, Object>toMap(i -> new String[]{"name", "id"}[i], i -> x[i]))).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>::new));
```

Comment: `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>::new)` is an unnecessary complication. You can use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` and the compiler will infer the generic type here. But you can also just use `Collectors.toList()` as the `results` variable is declared as `List` and it’s not specified that it has to be an `ArrayList`.